# MySQLi: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysqli

I realize that similar questions have been asked multiple times, but none of the solutions offered there have worked for me. I've also studied php.net and MySQLi tutorials, but can't figure this one out.

```
$dbconnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "***", "***", "***");
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect2, $_POST['age']);
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbconnect2, $_POST['country']);
$poll = "poll-s1";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "INSERT INTO tblpoll (poll, quizdate, age, country) VALUES($poll, $today, $age, $country)");
```

Produced the error:
mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

(On both the lines for $age and $country.)

The values for $age and $country come from the previous page, e.g.:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="show.php">
<select name="age" class="formadmin" id="age">
            <option value="no" selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="under10">Under 10</option>
            <option value="11-20">11-20</option>
            <option value="21-30">21-30</option>
</select>
<select name="country" class="formadmin" id="country">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
</select>
</form>
```

(truncated lists)

I've not done MySQLi INSERT before so I'm probably making a basic error, but I can't spot it.

What am I missing?

Comment: You are passing `$db_connect2` instead of `$db_connect`

Comment: Also in the last row you are passing `$dbconnect`

Comment: TonyMorello, you're the man. Thank you. Stupid mistake that I could have spent another 8 hours chasing. It works now.

Comment: I'll post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `$db_connect2` instead of `$db_connect`

Answer (score -1):

Not your problem, but the same error:

> MySQLi: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ...

I had just not imported the right module. In my case, I ran a SQL command from one connection (done with the imported `config1.php`), and then I needed to log into another connection (done with the imported config2.php). If I then imported only "config1.php", I got the error in question, but it had to be:

```php
include ("config1.php");
include ("config2.php");
```

By this, the logging function did not get null parameters for the user + connection anymore, but the global variables from the `config2.php`.

You can debug this by using echo(), in my case by checking the parameters each by each to the php code, for example:

```php
echo($user)
echo($conn)
```

which both had a 0 in the echo. You saw `00` in the response of the front end. You can see this response with:

- either: F12 --> Debugger --> Breakpoints
- or: F12 --> Network --> Response